# Автоматическая авторизация

Tags: linux, ubuntu, администрирование, синхронизация, rsync

Привет всем!
В общем, есть Ubuntu Server, куда я заливаю файлы. Также установлен и настроен rsync. Есть Ubuntu-клиент, куда я синхронизирую файлы с сервера.

Ввожу на клиенте команду:

```
rsync -urlogt --delete-after user@192.168.56.10:/home/user/public_html
/testsite/upload /home/user/Рабочий\ стол/
```

запрашивает пароль, и все синхронизируется.

Далее создал файл с паролем /etc/rsyncd.scrt

После чего при вводе команды:

```
rsync -urlogt --delete-after --password-file=/etc/rsyncd.scrt
user@192.168.56.10:/home/user/public_html/testsite/upload
/home/user/Рабочий\ стол/backup
```

выводит сообщение

> the password-file option may only be used when accessing an rsync
>   daemon

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Опция password-file доступна только при доступу к rsync, запущенному в режиме демона. Ваш переводчик.

Comment: В rsync начал разбираться только час-два назад. Это значит, что на клиенте необходимо запустить "демон" через команду, например, /etc/init.d/rsync restart ?

Comment: Я не разбирался вообще никогда, но, думаю, да.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Разобрался. Оказывается в файле конфигурации демона имя модуля **[upload]** было написано неверно. 
Использовал команду:

```
rsync -urlogt --delete-after --password-file=/etc/rsyncd.scrt adam@192.168.56.10::upload 
/home/adam/Рабочий\ стол/upload
```

В итоге все повесил на **cron**:

```
*/1 * * * * root rsync -urlogt --delete-after --password-file=/etc/rsyncd.scrt 
adam@192.168.56.10::upload /home/adam/Рабочий\ стол/upload
```

Answer (score 2):

приведённая команда использует возможности openssh для подключения к 192.168.56.10.

чтобы подключаться, используя openssh без ввода пароля, воспользуйтесь аутентификацией по ключу.

на машине, где выполняете приведённую команду, сгенерируйте, если ещё нет (проверить можно по наличию/отсутствию файла `~/.ssh/id_rsa`), openssh-ключ:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

а затем скопируйте его в учётную запись `user@192.168.56.10`:

```
$ ssh-copy-id user@192.168.56.10
```

Comment: Спасибо. А возможно использование без openssh?
В одном туториале есть команда для синхронизации 
`rsync -urlogt --delete-after --password-file=/etc/rsyncd.scrt
 backup@192.168.0.5::data /BACKUP/data`. Например, у меня путь до папки бэкапа `/home/user/public_html/testsite/upload`. Ввожу команду `rsync -urlogt --delete-after --password-file=/etc/rsyncd.scrt user@192.168.56.10::upload /home/user/Рабочий\ стол`.
Выдает unknown module 'upload'. Не понимаю где ошибка:((

Comment: да, возможно, конечно. но для этого, во-первых, надо настроить rsyncd на «серверной» стороне, во-вторых, протокол rsync, насколько мне известно, не подразумевает шифрования, и в-третьих у вас и так всё отлично и безопасно работает.