# Как подключиться к виртуалке удаленно?

Tags: debian, виртуализация, kvm

Я установил себе виртуалку на сервер (не знаю, правильно ли я сделал). Виртуализация - libvirt+qemu+kvm.

Все делал через утилиту ***virsh***. Сейчас показывает, что запущена 1 виртуалка.

А как к ней подключиться, чтобы поставить операционную систему и использовать ее как сервер?

Answer (score 1):

чтобы подключиться к консоли вашей виртуальной машины, вам как минимум необходим [беспарольный (по ключу) ssh-доступ к серверу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/425066/178576), на котором запущена эта виртуальная машина.

1. более простое средство — *virt-viewer* (из одноимённого [пакета](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=virt-viewer), но в wheezy он, к сожаление, «поломан»):

   ```
   $ virt-viewer --connect qemu+ssh://пользователь@сервер/system имя-виртуальной-машины
   ```
2. более «навороченное» средство — *virt-manager* (из одноимённого [пакета](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=virt-manager)). это программа с gui. сначала надо будет настроить соединение с вашим сервером:

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

   потом подключиться к нему (двойной «щелчок» левой кнопкой мыши по созданному соединению), затем в развернувшемся списке двойным «щелчком» откройте консоль выбранной виртуальной машины:

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а есть ***virt-manager*** для mac os?

Comment: googel://virt-manager+mac+os → http://stackoverflow.com/q/3921814/4827341

Comment: извините, может я тупой, но я не могу понять как мне запустить виртуалку как сервер(((

Comment: какой смысл вы вкладываете в выражение «как сервер»?

Comment: я у меня есть сервер, который я использую в своих целях. я поставил виртуалку, хочу ее настроить и отдать другу, что бы он использовал ее как сервер. я уже кучу перерыл, повсюду все разное и ничего дельного...

Comment: повторяю вопрос: какой смысл вы вкладываете в выражение «как сервер»?

Comment: что бы можно было там установить os и она была доступна извне

Comment: какой **конкретный** смысл вы вкладываете в выражение «доступна извне»? как вы видите эту «доступность»?

Comment: исходя из вашего [предыдущего вопроса](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/498494/178576) я делаю вывод, что у вас есть сервер, доступный из интернета по ip-адресу. и вы, видимо, хотите заиметь **ещё один** сервер, доступный по **другому** ip-адресу. провайдер, предоставивший вам сервер, уже выделил вам **второй** ip-адрес?

Comment: нет, такого я не делал, у них есть возможность просто докупить ip